# jQuery: Automatically trigger hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hover mousein mouseout setup as follows for a list item:

```
$("#main-nav li a").hover(function() {
                $el = $(this);
                leftPos = $el.position().left;
                newWidth = $el.parent().width();
                $magicNav.stop().animate({
                    left: leftPos,
                    width: newWidth
                });
            }, function() {
                t1 = $(".current-menu-item a").position().left;
                t2 = $(".current-menu-item a").parent().width();
                $magicNav.stop().animate({
                    left: t1,
                    width: t2
                });    
            });
```

And i want to automatically trigger a hover on '.current-menu-item a' as soon as someone enters the website or the page is loaded.

At the moment, i use `$(".current-menu-item a").trigger('hover');` and it doesn't work.

Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current-menu-item a").mouseover();
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".current-menu-item a").mouseover();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Uttara, the first one doesn't work, but i tried $(window).load(function(){
    $(".current-menu-item a").mouseover();
}); 

and it works

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".current-menu-item a").trigger('mouseenter');
```

Hover is not a real event (it's a contrived one by jQuery, made up of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`). In any case, it is a two-stage process, so not logically triggerable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use mouseover not hover  like so

`$(".current-menu-item a").trigger('mouseover');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').trigger('eventName');
```