# Can't trigger 'hover' event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's 'hover' trigger doesn't seem to work. My code is simple:

```
<div id='el'>Content</div>

// does not work
$('#el').on('hover', function() { console.log('is not triggered'); });
$('#el').trigger('hover');

// works for various strings: 'foo', 'click', 'hove', 'keyup', etc.
$('#el').on('foo', function() { console.log('is triggered'); });
$('#el').trigger('foo');
```

Any handler I bind to this div with `.on` responds to `.trigger` except for the 'hover' event. A handler bound with `.on('hover', handler)` does respond to me manually hovering on the element, but it does not respond to programmatic triggers. I've tested this in both Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas? Is this a bug in jQuery?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/PSS4x/

Comment: dont forget the `<script>` tag

Comment: @Tats_innit that works but it doesn't work onload. At least for my browser.

Comment: @Tats_innit: Your demo doesn't work for me, but works when you use the underlying events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Automatically trigger hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720903/jquery-automatically-trigger-hover)

Comment: @user1689607 http://jsfiddle.net/ymAFh/ `:)`

Comment: @Steven Thanks man **demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/ymAFh/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trigger the `'mouseenter'` or `'mouseleave'` events.

The `'hover'` syntax is a jQuery shortcut for binding `'mouseenter'` and `'mouseleave'`.

Comment: This is not working for the jquery version greater than 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger CSS pseudo selectors with jQuery. But you can do anything else, such as create a function and have that triggered.