# CSS: How to fake a :hover state?

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

Here, I have several divs. When mouse hover them, there would be a transition effect. (like the left-inner corner)

I want to fake a hover at first. For example, make the left-outer corner div in :hover state at first, without user's actual hover action. And then, when user really hovers over other divs, the fake hover state cancelled.

For HTML & CSS：

```
    <div class="story" id="target">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="story">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="story">
      <!--content-->
    </div> 

.story{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2A2A2A;
  &:hover{
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lighten(#2A2A2A, 20%);
  }
}
```

What I want to do:

At start, the `div#target` is forced into `:hover` state(So it has a different background). Later, when the user starts to use his mouse and hover to other divs, other divs changes into `:hover` state, and the `div#target` go back to normal state.

It's pretty much like a `autofocus` when we using input field

UPDATES:
I want to trigger hover state of an element as soon as someone enters this page.

[jQuery: Automatically trigger hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720903/jquery-automatically-trigger-hover)

Comment: Swap your hover state css with normal state css. fwiw.

Comment: how is hover state managed? Provide some sample html and css ( and script if applicable). Without code it is anyone's guess how your page works. You should be providing code not images in questions here unless the image helps explain the code. Image provided has very little value

Comment: would likely do better using a class instead of `:hover`, then use script to toggle class. @Victor provided simplest hover code using jQuery, then use toggleClass()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a class declaration to your `:hover` CSS rule like this:

```
.story:hover,
.story.hover {
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lighten(#2A2A2A, 20%);
}
```

And now you can use JS to add classes to the `.story` elements to mimic the hover effect:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $(".story").eq(0).addClass('hover');
});
```

This will add the hover effect to the first `.story` element on document-ready.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fKupb/

I suggest using this method because it plays nice with CSS. If you have an event handler setup for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` then you can use JS to trigger those event handlers using jQuery's `.trigger()` function: `$(".story").eq(0).trigger('mouseenter');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but jQuery's `hover()` function would be what you want

```
$("#div").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red"); //or whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Change `this` to `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of jQuery, this can be accomplished in the following manner:

```
.box, .left-box {
    /* Default styling. */
}

.box:hover, .left-box {
    /* Hover coloring for box. */
}

.left-box:hover {
    /* Default coloring for box. */
}
```

In effect, this is some sample code:

```
.box, .left-box {
    background-color: #666666;
    padding: 1em;
}

.box:hover, .left-box {
    background-color: #999999;
}

.left-box:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: This is good. But can we use a simpler one? After all, we just are simulating a user's hover action.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` offers `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` events. You can use them like this if you want:

```
$("#div").hover( function(e){
    // hover in
}, function(e) {
    // hover out
});
```

or simply with the `hoverIn`, like this:

```
$("#div").hover( function(e) {
    // hover in
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#someObj").on('mouseover', function () {
        //do something on mouse over
    });

    $("#someObj").on('mouseleave', function () {
        //do something on mouse out
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created a solution for you check it here hope it will help

```
<a href='http://jsfiddle.net/vishalj/FQysN/1/'>jsfiddle</a>
```