# Change CSS pseudoclass state via a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, pseudo-class

I am trying to create a webpage where users can play a piano by either clicking on the "keys" or pressing the corresponding buttons on their keyboard. I have the buttons animated using CSS pseudoclasses following the method outlined in [this blog post](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/animation/3d-button/).

***blog post TL;DR:***
The button is made up of multiple `<span>` elements stacked on top of each other, with `:active` and `:hover` pseudoclasses triggering a `transform: translateY()` animation.

Is there a way to toggle the CSS state of an element using JS? Can I force an `:active` and `:hover` to trigger the CSS animation? Trying to figure out a way to get my `handleOnKeyDown` and `handleKeyUp` to trigger the CSS animation that I've already written.

To show where things are at currently:

```js
const synth = new Tone.PolySynth(Tone.Synth).set(
    { oscillator: { type: 'triangle8' } }
).toDestination()

const makeKeyboardControls = () => {
    let notes = ['F3', 'G3', 'A3'];
    let keys =  ['a', 's', 'd'];
    const keyboardControls = {}
    for(let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
      keyboardControls[keys[i]] = {pressed: false, note: notes[i]}
    }
    return keyboardControls
}

const keyboardControls = makeKeyboardControls()

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  const key = e.key.toLowerCase();
  if(keyboardControls[key] && !keyboardControls[key].pressed){
    synth.triggerAttack(keyboardControls[key].note)
    keyboardControls[key].pressed = true
  }
}

const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    const key = e.key.toLowerCase();
    if(keyboardControls[key] && keyboardControls[key].pressed){
      synth.triggerRelease(keyboardControls[key].note)
      keyboardControls[key].pressed = false
    }
  }
  
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)

const handleMouseDown = (note) => {
  synth.triggerAttack(note)
}

const handleMouseUp = (note) => {
  synth.triggerRelease(note)
}

const handleMouseEnter = (e, note) => {
  if(e.buttons === 1){
    synth.triggerAttack(note)
  }
}

const handleMouseLeave = (note) => {
  synth.triggerRelease(note)  
}

let f = 'F3'
let g = 'G3'
let a = 'A3'

const aButton = document.getElementById('a')
const sButton = document.getElementById('s')
const dButton = document.getElementById('d')

aButton.addEventListener('mousedown', 
    () => handleMouseDown('F3')
)

aButton.addEventListener('mouseup', 
    () => handleMouseUp('F3')
)

aButton.addEventListener('mouseenter',
    (e) => handleMouseEnter(e, f)
)

aButton.addEventListener('mouseleave',
    () => handleMouseLeave(f)
)

sButton.addEventListener('mousedown',
    () => handleMouseDown('G3')
)

sButton.addEventListener('mouseup', 
    () => handleMouseUp('G3')
)

sButton.addEventListener('mouseenter',
    (e) => handleMouseEnter(e, g)
)

sButton.addEventListener('mouseleave',
    () => handleMouseLeave(g)
)

dButton.addEventListener('mousedown',
    () => handleMouseDown('A3')
)

dButton.addEventListener('mouseup', 
    () => handleMouseUp('A3')
)

dButton.addEventListener('mouseenter',
    (e) => handleMouseEnter(e, a)
)

dButton.addEventListener('mouseleave',
    () => handleMouseLeave(a)
)
```

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}

.body{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.pushable {
  position: relative;
  
  /* border: none; */
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.3rem 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  transition: filter 250ms;
}
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 0.25);
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translateY(2px);
  transition:
    transform
    600ms
    cubic-bezier(.3, .7, .4, 1);
}
.edge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    hsl(340deg 100% 16%) 0%,
    hsl(340deg 100% 32%) 8%,
    hsl(340deg 100% 32%) 92%,
    hsl(340deg 100% 16%) 100%
  );
}

.front {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 42px 22px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  will-change: transform;
  background: hsl(345deg 100% 47%);
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  transition:
    transform
    600ms
    cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

.pushable:hover {
  filter: brightness(110%);
}

.pushable:hover .front {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  transition:
    transform
    250ms
    cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1.5);
}

.pushable:active:hover .front {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform 34ms;
}

.pushable:hover .shadow {
  transform: translateY(4px);
  transition:
    transform
    250ms
    cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1.5);
}

.pushable:active:hover .shadow {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  transition: transform 34ms;
}

.pushable:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone@14.7.77/build/Tone.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/tinycolor2@1.4.2/tinycolor.js"></script> -->
<body class="body">
  <div class="buttons">
    <label id="a" class="pushable">
      <span class="shadow"></span>
      <span class="edge"></span>
      <span class="front">a</span>
    </label>
    <label id="s" class="pushable">
      <span class="shadow"></span>
      <span class="edge"></span>
      <span class="front">s</span>
    </label>
    <label id="d" class="pushable">
      <span class="shadow"></span>
      <span class="edge"></span>
      <span class="front">d</span>
    </label>
  </div>

</body>
```

(also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GarrettBodley/xoku4za2/40/))

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: No need to force an `:active` or `:hover` when you can simply add a class name, and style that class to behave the same as `:active` or `:hover`, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773812/css-how-to-fake-a-hover-state

Comment: I could add a class name, but triggering animation via adding/removing a class is much laggier and slows the page down too much. I was hoping there might be a way to avoid altering classNames if possible.